# gnuplot terminals don't work anymore

Tags: gnuplot

I use gnuplot for a long time now, but today, my terminals (png, pngcairo etc.) don't work anymore and gnuplot send me a long long long "message" like :

```
?PNG

IHDR?,?2PLTE???????????????@??Ai??? ?@???0`??@?????ԥ**??@??333MMMfff???????????????????22????U?????݂?????????d?"?".?W??p?͇???????????P????E??r?z?挽?k??
                                                                      ??ܠ? ?????ݠݐP@Uk/???@?@??`??`?????@??@??`??p?????????ͷ???????????|?@?? ???????????????___??X/ pHYs???+IDATx?? v?H
                           ?s?>:???W?Hڎ??Ih?Y???X   ?*??/p@S?Ng???q???T?+B6?
                                                                               B^4?????L??PP??n?????!?w?1o?Y%?r$???W?
?͸??S   ?;??&?C=??^?EU?Ñ??'????y?G??m?E??$s???%????ro??q[?ڊ??y???ҳ_?hTt???M???c??G=???Ջ???\??y]? 1U?G??ͳ??G??Cpu}?j?z\?ս????{??m{ֳ
???|Q??=^u/?[??}.?z??G??u?ţ?|8I???ʊ|Q?_?Z?{??۹?n?QݯU????|
                                                         ?&ۜ???50cԺ?v
```

I tried to reinstall gnuplot but there was no change.

Do you have an idea ?

PS :

1. I'm on a macOX El Capitan.
2. I installed gnuplot with `brew install gnuplot --with-qt --with-cairo`.
3. The qt terminal work fine.

Comment: you forgot `set out 'my_file.png'`

Comment: I'm so ashamed !!! You prefer not to know the time I spent on this... Thank you very much @gboffi

Comment: Why the downvote ? The gnuplot error message is really unclear and I didn't find its interpretation on the internet. If another gnuplot user get this type of error message it should help.